# (H2O.ai) How to handle empty timestamp values in hex.genmodel.easy.EasyPredictModelWrapper.predictBinomial

Tags: java, h2o

Using h2o, I have used a .csv data frame that includes a column of dates, some of which are NULL, to train a model. Looking at the .hex dataframe that was output by h2o Flow UI after parsing the input .csv file, the null values are represented by `.`s and the remaining dates are represented as timestamp doubles (ie. milliseconds since epoch time).

When trying to use the model's MOJO file in a java program to make predictions, on a dataset, I am getting the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at hex.genmodel.easy.EasyPredictModelWrapper.fillRawData(EasyPredictModelWrapper.java:554)
        at hex.genmodel.easy.EasyPredictModelWrapper.predict(EasyPredictModelWrapper.java:615)
        at hex.genmodel.easy.EasyPredictModelWrapper.preamble(EasyPredictModelWrapper.java:489)
        at hex.genmodel.easy.EasyPredictModelWrapper.predictBinomial(EasyPredictModelWrapper.java:303)
        at SimpleCsvPredictor.predictCsv(SimpleCsvPredictor.java:287)
        at SimpleCsvPredictor.main(SimpleCsvPredictor.java:210)
```

since I am handling NULL values in the dataset's date column by setting them t null in the [RowData](https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-turan/4/docs-website/h2o-genmodel/javadoc/hex/genmodel/easy/RowData.html) object that h2o's model EasyPredictionModelWrapper can make predictions on.

The problem is that, for this column, the model is expecting a Double value. But there is no Double value to pass in because the value is null. Note that I cannot just set these null values to 0.0 because of how the model is trained (since not all the dates are null, so setting some to zero would be misrepresenting the particular sample the the model). So how can I fix this or what can I put in the place of a null where a Double is expected?

Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I do to the date `String`s before I `row.put("date_field", "<date string>")` some `<date string>` into a `RowData` object (see [here](https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-turan/4/docs-website/h2o-genmodel/javadoc/hex/genmodel/easy/RowData.html)) that `EasyPredictModelWrapper` can predict on:

```
/**
     *
     * @param str_date (in MM/dd/yyyy form)
     * @return string representation of timestamp value, either the string value of the str_date timestamp or "NULL"
     * if can parse str_date to Date object, else returns null
     */
    private String dateString2TimestampString(String str_date) {
        if (str_date.toUpperCase().equals("NULL")) {
            return "NULL";
        } else {
            try {
                // convert date (MM/DD/YYYY) string to java date
                DateFormat formatter;
                formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
                Date date = (Date) formatter.parse(str_date);

                // convert date string to timestamp (since epoch time) (double??)
                double epochTimestamp = (double) date.getTime();
                return new BigDecimal(epochTimestamp).toPlainString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("** dateString2TimestampString: could not parse string \"" + str_date + "\" to Date object");
                System.out.println(e.getClass().getCanonicalName());
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                System.exit(1);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Be sure to set the `convertInvalidNumberToNa` config (see near the top of [this](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-genmodel/src/main/java/hex/genmodel/easy/EasyPredictModelWrapper.java) code) for the wrapper as well so that is nicely handles `"NULL"` strings. E.g.:

```
EasyPredictModelWrapper model = new EasyPredictModelWrapper(
            new EasyPredictModelWrapper.Config()
                .setModel(MojoModel.load(MODEL_CLASS_NAME))
                .setConvertUnknownCategoricalLevelsToNa(true)
                .setConvertInvalidNumbersToNa(true)
        );
```